# Loop printing lots of graphs in order (PDF) using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a large dataset as a result of a bayesian logistic regression. The dataset contains parameter estimates, confidence intervals, etc (see below for head).

```
        mean         sd confint_2.5 confint_97.5     Rhat     median    spec    Errorup Errordown
1 -0.7897597 0.18668304  -1.1759960   -0.4517294 1.002211 -0.7811156 Marvulg -0.3293862 -1.957112
2 -0.7891327 0.08145761  -0.9570086   -0.6380287 1.000155 -0.7861764 Viotric -0.1481477 -1.743185
3 -0.6619662 0.26049168  -1.2203315   -0.2059030 1.045208 -0.6440501 Antdioi -0.4381470 -1.864382
4 -0.6571516 0.17940842  -1.0417642   -0.3364415 1.008100 -0.6470382 Eleacic -0.3105968 -1.688802
5 -0.6526717 0.20005184  -1.0816375   -0.2968111 1.005126 -0.6394952 Antcotu -0.3426842 -1.721133
6 -0.6497648 0.16620699  -1.0081607   -0.3555847 1.003738 -0.6384035 Triflav -0.2828188 -1.646564
```

I have a total of 714 rows of data, sorted (mean) from low to high. I use this code to plot 50 at a time, where a3_sort is a subset of 50 rows of data (so manually doing `a3_sort <- a3[n:n,),` after which I print the subset and proceed to the next 50):

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = a3_sort, mapping = aes(x = reorder(spec, mean), y = mean, ymin = confint_97.5, ymax = confint_2.5))+
  geom_pointrange()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2)+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab ("species") +ylab ("mean (credibility interval)")+
  theme_bw()
```

This works, and I get what I want, but there must be a less manual labour way to do this?

My question: Is there a way to loop this procedure, automatically saving the PDF in the working directory?

Below an example of what one plot looks like:
[image]

Comment: So do you want a plot for each 50 rows dataframe obtained from your original data?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So 15 plots total without having to manually subset and save the plots.

Comment: I have added a possible solution to your issue. Please check and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution. I tested with dummy data `DF` with `714` rows and same columns as you have. `DF` in your case is your sorted dataframe of `714` rows and the variables you have. I have set the code so that you can change if you require a width larger than 50.

```
library(zoo)
#Create keys; change 50 if you want a larger window
keys <- seq(1, nrow(DF), 50)
vals=1:length(keys)
#Flag to allocate the position and values
#na.locf is used to complete NA so that we have same index
DF$Flag <- NA
DF$Flag[keys]<-vals
DF$Flag <- na.locf(DF$Flag)
#Then split by flag
ListData <- split(DF,DF$Flag)
#Function to create plot
myplot <- function(x)
{
  tplot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = x, mapping = aes(x = reorder(spec, mean), y = mean, ymin = confint_97.5, ymax = confint_2.5))+
    geom_pointrange()+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2)+
    coord_flip()+
    xlab ("species") +ylab ("mean (credibility interval)")+
    theme_bw()
  return(tplot)
}
#Replicate plots
LPlots <- lapply(ListData,myplot)
#Export to pdf
pdf('Myplots.pdf',width = 14)
for(i in c(1:length(LPlots)))
{
  plot(LPlots[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

In the end, you will have your plots in pdf. I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Hi Duck, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this worked for me! I made a few adjustments (keeping the axis length the same for different plots for example). Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 1):

This approach could be adapted to your case:

```r
# Some dummy data:

df <- data.frame(g = letters[1:24],
                 min = sample(0:10, 24, replace = TRUE),
                 mid = sample(11:20, 24, replace = TRUE),
                 max = sample(21:30, 24, replace = TRUE))
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

# list of the rows you want printing, this could be automated

plot_range <- list(p1_6 = 1:6, p7_12 = 7:12, p13_18  = 13:18, p19_24 = 19:24)

# plotting function which also sets a title and plot name

gg_plot <- function(df, plot_rows){

title <- paste("Automatic plot rows: ", min(plot_rows), "to", max(plot_rows))
plot_nm <- paste("plots", min(plot_rows), max(plot_rows), sep = "_")
    
p <- ggplot(df[plot_rows, ])+
  geom_segment(aes(x = min , xend = max, y = g, yend = g))+
  geom_point(aes(x = mid, y = g))+
  ggtitle(title)

print(ggsave(plot_nm, p, device = "pdf"))

}

# purrr function which acts as a loop to print each graph and allows a different data frame to be used.

walk(plot_range, ~gg_plot(df = df, plot_rows = .x))
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> NULL
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> NULL
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> NULL
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>